# Populate EntitySet from List<int>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class UserAdminEditViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Usergroup> Usergroups { get; set; }
    public IList<int> UsergroupID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }

    public UserAdminEditViewModel() {}
}
```

And in my post-action in my controller I got:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UserEdit(UserAdminEditViewModel userobj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // userobj.User.UsersUsergroups is EnitySet<UsersUsergroups> User.UsersUsergroups
                userobj.User.UsersUsergroups = userobj.UsergroupID;  //  IList<int> UserAdminEditViewModel.UsergroupID

                us.SaveUser(userobj.User);
            }
            catch
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("SomeError", "errrrrrrrrror");
            }
        }
```

How can I populate userobj.User.UsersUsergroups with the list of int's that resides in userobj.UsergroupID?

I get:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1'"

Thanks in advance
/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try:

```
for each(var usergroup in userobj.UsergroupID)
{
   userobj.User.UsersUsergroups.Add(usergroup)
}
```

instead of:

```
userobj.User.UsersUsergroups = userobj.UsergroupID;  //  IList<int> UserAdminEditViewModel.UsergroupID
```

Comment: For some reason I get no methods or properties for userobj.User.UsersUsergroups. I suspect my model is wrong? And I need to use some joins or summet?